# Why is $g(X)$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ independent random variables and $\phi$ be a function such that $E[\phi(X,Y)]<\infty$. Let $g(x)=E[\phi(x,Y)]$.

We need to show that $g(X)=E[\phi(X,Y)|X]$.

However I cant show $g(X)$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable (the rest of the problem is easy). Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Show that for any measurable $g$ we have $\sigma(g(X))\subseteq\sigma(X)$. In particular, since $g(X)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(g(X))$ it is also measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$.